# Discord bot how to send a message (simplest form)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to send a message with my discord bot the simplest way possible, online I'll I've found is stuff that are too complex for me, and I can't get them too work.

```
require("dotenv").config(); //to start process from .env file
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, //adds server functionality
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping, //gets messages from our bot.
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        //GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
        //GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
    ]
})
client.once("ready", () =>{
    console.log("Bot is online!"); //message when bot is online
})
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);


client.on('message',
function (messages){
    if(messages.content.toLocaleLowerCase()==='hello') 
    messages.channel.send('Hello: ' + messages.author.username); //reply hello word message with senders name
})
```

If I change my code to this, it still doesn't work:

```js
const {
  Client,
  Partials,
  Collection,
  GatewayIntentBits,
} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.User,
    Partials.GuildMember,
    Partials.Reaction,
  ],
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't change your code to something completely different from your original question. This is still a duplicate. If you've added the `MessageContent` intent, use `messageContent` instead of the `message` event. It's deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord introduced the `MessageContent` intent a while ago which has to be enabled in your code (via `GatewayIntentBits`) and also has to be enabled in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://canary.discord.com/developers/) as "Privileged Intent" (Can be found under your bot > "Bot" (on the left navigation menu) > Pivileged Gateway Intents > Message Content Intet > enable this option).